# Rewrite routes at .htaccess

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite routes with HTACCESS but I am not able to. I am using MVC and currently the routes is generated of the type http: //localhost/realestate/web/index.php? Route = storefront

My idea is that they remain of the type http: // localhost / realestate / web / storefront

Ie omit the index.php? Path =

I am currently using this code:

```
 RewriteEngine on 


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([a-zAZ0-9]+)$ ?ruta=$1
```

My php code for the treatment of these routes is the following:

```
 $map = array(
    'home' => array('controller' => 'Controller', 'action' => 'home'),
    'escaparate' => array('controller' => 'Controller', 'action' => 'escaparate'),
    );

//Parsing

if(isset($_GET['ruta'])){
    if(isset($map[$_GET['ruta']])){
        $ruta = $_GET['ruta'];
    }
    else{
        //404
        header('404 Not Found');
        echo '<html><body><p style color:red "><b>ERROR: No existe la ruta '. $_GET['ruta'] . '</b></p></body></html>';
        exit;
    }
}
else{
    $ruta = 'home';
}
```

But I can't, I have tried various ways that I have found around here. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: A "route" is a rule that maps a URL or URLs to the code that is responsible for handling the content.   Rewrite rules are routing rules.   Did you mean to say that you are routing URLs with rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes, I'm telling that I want to make disappear a part of the route that is index.php?ruta= for a /. That is im trying to do.

Comment: Please invest a bit of time to fix your question. It appears you are using three different words for what is actually the same thing: "Route", "Path" and "ruta". Also take care to remove stray whitespaces in your code. _Be precise_ in your question, otherwise you just add complexity and trigger miss understandings.